# setCompoundDrawables from URL

Tags: android

I'm trying to put a drawable from URL near a TextView, this way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(rankImg).getContent());
                        Drawable bitmap2 = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),bitmap);
                        holder.divisionTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(bitmap2,0,0, 0);
```

Since **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds** do not accept drawable as parameter, I can an error.
how do I convert my drawable to fit this method arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. `new URL(rankImg).getContent()` does not do a network call to get the content of the image. The best way is to use a image loading library like Picasso, Glide or UniversalImageLoader.

Here is a code piece to get a Bitmap object from UniversalImageLoader:

```
bitmap = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(rankImg,
                            new ImageSize((int) context.getResources().getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width),
                                    (int) context.getResources().getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height)));
```